# Doing research as an undergraduate student

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, education, advice, publishing

How I can start a research on algebraic geometry which can lead to a published paper as an undergraduate student? I already have taken graduate courses like algebraic geometry, homological algebra, algebraic number theory. Can some one recommend papers to read?

Answer (score 2):

If you are eager about starting research I would suggest you talk to your professor of trust or other supervisors that are doing research. They are the able to point you in the right direction and can most likely help you getting something published if you achieve relevant results.

Comment: Mostly, do not wast their time for  an undergraduate

Comment: I'm sorry for you. I'm pretty sure my professors would "waste their time" on me :D. You could also just ask for a certain direction or some topics after a lecture. This won't cost them too much of their time. Good luck to you.

Comment: @ahmadrezakhazaie Just make sure that you are respectful of their time. Most professors (esp those who have taught you and you scored well in their class) are willing to sit down for 15 mins to discuss / guide you.

Comment: And also I should mention that we do not have algebraic geometriest in our department , so I emailed to professors from other math departments and they did not help me.